# update only one document id in subcollection in firestore in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

is it possible to update only one document id in a firestore subcollection, I have been searching for solution but all I can find is to query all documents. if I use querySnapshot.foreach() all documents in a subcollection with the same field value gets updated. Using .where() also query all documents and not a specific id, but I am only trying to update one. I am trying to use the document id but I could not figure out how to call the id for the subcollection. Is there a way to do that?

```
const currentUser=firebase.auth().currentUser;
const userPost= firebase.firestore().collection('users') 
                .doc(currentUser.uid).collection("post");

const EditPost = async (event) => {
 event.preventDefault();

 await userPost
  .doc() <-- here I've been trying to put the subcollection doc id 
  .set({
    title: title,
    body: body,
    updatedAt: date,
  }, { merge: true })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
 }
```

here is a sample screenshot of the firestore subcollection structure [image] [image: subcollection structure]. Currently I tried using uuidv4 so I can also create a field value of postId upon adding a new document, because I was planning on just calling the postId as a document id but it was also inside the subcollection ducument.

Comment: I'm unclear where you are stuck.  It's definitely possible to update a single document if you know it's ID.  This is covered in the [documentation](https://twitter.com/CodingDoug). You have to pass the ID to `doc()`.

Comment: yeah I could not figure out the right way to call one document id for the sub collection

Comment: There is only one way - pass the ID to `doc()`.  You're passing nothing right now.

Comment: yeah I have already pass an id where I even used a uuidv4 but does not work either. So that is just an example of what I am currently using where I couldn't figure out the right way to call the id for the doc() in a sub collection. What I am talking about is the sub collection not the root collection. I am currently trying something for now don't know if this will work.

Comment: I'm still not clear where you're stuck.  Either you know the ID of the existing document, or you don't.  If you don't, you have to query to find it.

Comment: I can only make it work if I query all document but every field value gets updated as well, but what I'm trying to do is just update one document and not all. Currently I am stuck at how to call the id for only one document of a sub collection.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your database with the entire path of the document you want to update?

Comment: Here is an example[1] about how to insert a subcollection using node js. Also, as @Renaud Tarnec mentioned, it will be helpful to see your documents' structure. Finally, if you are following a guide, it will be helpful if you share it too.

[1]https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I attached a sample image of my firestore subcollection structure above.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you show/detail the path of the `userPosts` subcollection?

Comment: I added another attachment above for the path of the subcollection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out how to call a document id for a single document in a subcollection and edit only the field of a specific document. Might not be the best solution but I'm sharing this for those who are having similar problem to mine.

I have a queried list of post in my postlist.js and each has a unique key which is equivalent to the document id inside the subcollection.

```
post 1 - edit
post 2 - edit
post 3 - edit
```

then on my route I used the useParams id using react router. using Link I go to the posteditor page, PostEditor.js.

```
<Route path="/posteditor/:id" component={PostEditor} />
```

by using the id from useParams inside the PostEditor.js I can now assigned the id inside the .doc() in my EditPost function.

```
const PostEditor = () => {
  const { id } = useParams

  const userPosts = ....;

  const EditPost = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    await userPosts
     .doc(id) <------*here I used the id from useParams*
     .set({
       title: title,
       body: body,
       updatedAt: date,
     }, { merge: true })
     .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
     })
  }

  return ( //// )
}
```

Now I can edit a single document and manage each document separately inside the subcollection. As I said it might not be the best solution but it works for me without error.

Answer (score 0):

You no need to use collectoin.set({}) you can also use collection.update({}) for update specific collection field.

```
db.collection("cities").doc("DC").update({
    capital: true
})
```

Here I mention code. this is [Link](https://medium.com/@aaron_lu1/firebase-cloud-firestore-add-set-update-delete-get-data-6da566513b1b) of reference site.

Comment: thank you but my question is about subcollection, I have no problem with the root collection.

Comment: you can use like this. db.collection("cities/subcollecion").doc("DC").update({
    capital: true
})

add path in collection.

Comment: yeah that is what actually the question about calling the doc id from a sub collection of a single document. Maybe my question is vague, but I have updated my post above to better understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption that you know the ID of the document in the `users` collection and the ID of the document in the `userPosts` collection, you can update this last document as follows:

```
const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
const userPosts = firebase.firestore().collection('users') 
                .doc(currentUser.uid).collection("userPosts");  // <= note the change here, from collection("post") to collection("userPosts")
 
const userPostId = "8ea3....";

const EditPost = async (event) => {
 event.preventDefault();

 await userPosts
  .doc(userPostId) 
  .set({
    title: title,
    body: body,
    updatedAt: date,
  }, { merge: true })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
 }
```

---

More generally, to create a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) to a document for which you know the path, you need to alternatively call the `collection()` and `doc()` methods.

You could also call the [`doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore#doc) method with a slash-separated path to a document, as shiwn below. Note that, since you point to a document,  the slash-separated path contains an even number of elements.

```
const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
const userPostId = "8ea3....";

const userPostRef = firebase.firestore().doc(`users/${currentUser}/userPosts/${userPostId}`)
```

Comment: been doing that but I am stuck with calling the sub collection doc id for a single document only, say for example doc(doc.id) will not work with this it gives me an error. So I changed the ids to uuid (pic above) and save a field with the name postId to store my doc id. Querying the postId gives me a list of all doc id where I can use in my doc(postId) like this it works, but because postId was querried all of the document field values gets updated at the same time which brings me back to start. Same thing as using querySnapshot.

Comment: I'm sorry but it is very hard to understand your goal... Already a lot of comments /responses where written around your question and it is still not clear what you are trying to do. I have the feeling that maybe you mix-up fields and documents. I would suggest you work out a very detailed explanation of your goal with some diagrams showing what you want to do, what are your input data and desired result.

Comment: what I am trying to do is to update a single document in a subcollection, but I am stuck on how to properly write the id inside the .doc() because I always end up updating all document ids with the same field name. If I have 2 document with different ids inside a collection both of them gets updated with the same values which is not what I'm trying to do. But anyways thanks for all the help I will study all of this.

Comment: What is not clear is "updating all document ids with the same field name". If you define one DocumentReference, you update only one document not several ones. Document paths are unique.

Comment: How do I define it in a subcollection without querying all documents? similar to doing .doc(doc.id) is it possible?

Comment: As Doug explained in one of his comments above: "Either you know the ID of the existing document, or you don't. If you don't, you have to query to find it".

Comment: I moved my subcollection to another root collection for now. Everything is working as I wanted to now. I am not still familiar with subcollection but I hope there will be more documentation and examples to study in the future

Comment: I got it now how to call a doc id of a single document in a subcollection by using the react router v5 useParams and it works. I posted the answer for reference.